# How to concatinate byte array in java

Tags: java, arrays

What is the simple method two concatenate two byte arrays in Java?
I used this function but got an error:

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 16

My function is:

```
public static byte[] concatinate(byte[] a, byte[] b) {
    byte[] c = new byte[100];
    for (int i = 0; i < (a.length + b.length); i++) {
        if (i < a.length) {
            c[i] = a[i];
        } else {
            c[i] = b[i];
        }
    }
    return c;
}
```

Comment: Here, `i > b.length`, will cause this exception.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, your code is *bound* to fail if `a.length + b.length > 100`. You should be using `a.length + b.length` as the length of `c`.

Yes, because when you've gone past `a.length`, you're still trying to use `b[i]`. Imagine a.length is 50 and b.length is 1. You've got 51 array elements to populate, but to populate c[50] you need b[0], not b[50].

All you need to change is this:

```
c[i] = b[i];
```

To this:

```
c[i] = b[i - a.length];
```

... or have two loops instead, as per Mureinik's answer. (I wouldn't expect either option to be significantly faster than the other, and they're definitely equivalent - you can use whichever you find most readable.)

However, I'd recommend using [`System.arraycopy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy-java.lang.Object-int-java.lang.Object-int-int-) instead:

```
public static byte[] concatenate(byte[] a, byte[] b) {
    byte[] c = new byte[a.length + b.length];
    System.arraycopy(a, 0, c, 0, a.length);
    System.arraycopy(b, 0, c, a.length, b.length);
    return c;
}
```

Much simpler :)

Comment: HOW WE CAN USE System.arraycopy ?

Comment: @AjmalMuhammad: a) did you try before asking? It's not terribly hard... b) there's an example in my answer

Comment: @Jon   c[i] = b[i - a.length]; is wrong you will miss some elements it is in if else

Comment: @raghavendra: Which elements will it miss? If `i` is less than `a.length`, it'll copy the value from `a`. If `i` is `a.length` or greater, it'll copy the value from `b`. A total of `a.length + b.length` elements are copied, which is correct. Where's the problem?

Comment: what about a[0] and b[0]

Comment: @raghavendra: `a[0]` will be copied when `i==0`, and `b[0]` will be copied when `i == a.length`.

Comment: ok thank you.. and i need one more help how to split  byte array in to two

Comment: @AjmalMuhammad: Try it yourself, then ask a separate question. Tackle one problem per post, but always do research *before* asking a question.

Comment: but you mentioned i - a.length

Comment: @raghavendra: Yes, indeed. So when `i == a.length`, then `b[i - a.length]` is `b[0]`. I suggest you work this through on a piece of paper with an example. It really *is* fine...

Comment: definitely later i will try out

Comment: ok thank you.. and i need one more help how to split byte array in to two

Comment: @raghavendra: What do you mean by "but too many conditions"? Basically, the `b[i - a.length]` is the logical equivalent to the `c[a.length + i]` in Mureinik's answer. (It's not clear what you mean by "the second answer".)

Comment: i mean ifelse in the loop

Comment: @AjmalMuhammad: So you said before. Please see my comment at 2015-07-10 08:57:42Z.

Comment: @raghavendra: So it's a single loop with an if/else vs two loops without. I think they're about equal in complexity myself... but System.arraycopy is better than either of them.

Comment: two loops length in single loop and a condition to it

Answer (score 1):

Just define an array the size of the combined two arrays, and iterate each of them **individually**:

```
public static byte[] concatinate(byte[] a, byte[] b) {
    byte[] c = new byte[a.length + b.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        c[i] = a[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
        c[a.length + i] = b[i];
    }

    return c;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The code for appending 2 byte[] was good.If you want to keep on appending the byte[] you can use this code....

byte[] readBytes ; // Your byte array .... //for eg. readBytes = "TestBytes".getBytes();

ByteArrayBuffer mReadBuffer = new ByteArrayBuffer(0 ) ; // Instead of 0, if you know the count of expected number of bytes, nice to input here

mReadBuffer.append(readBytes, 0, readBytes.length); // this copies all bytes from readBytes byte array into mReadBuffer
// Any new entry of readBytes, you can just append here by repeating the same call.

// Finally, if you want the result into byte[] form:
byte[] result = mReadBuffer.buffer();